# Filtering data with forms and Vuex without conditionals

Tags: javascript, redux, vue.js, vuex

In my component I am looping through a list of items:

```
  <item
       v-for="item in items"
       :key="item.id"
       :item="item">
  </item>
```

I have a getter which based on filter criteria sets state.items:

```
export const items = state => state.items.filter(item => item.mySex === state.filter);
```

These are the filter radio buttons:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexFilter" v-model="mySex" id="sex-female" value="1">
```

And I use watch to dispatch actions:

```
watch: {
      mySex(value) {
        this.$store.dispatch('setFilter', Number(value));
      },
    },
```

My problem is that when no filter is applied my getter sends back 0 results.
I would like to tackle that without using conditions.

Comment: You're going to need to put a condition somewhere. I'd do `state => { if (state.filter) { return state.items.filter(...) } else { return state.items } }`

Comment: anyway I can have two separate getters?

Comment: You mean for filtered and unfiltered data? You can, but then in your component, you'd still need to check to see if the filter is set to decide which getter to use. And that would be a lot more code